# How do i count the number of digits in a number not using /10 in C?

Tags: c

I need to count number of digits in binary-coded decimal, for example 00111001. I can't use typical /10 because it gets stuck on 2 last 0's and doesn't count them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(void) {
    int bcd, digits;
    printf("Input BCD number: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &bcd);
    for (digits = 0; (bcd / 10) != 0; digits++)
        bcd /= 10;
    printf("Number of digits is %d", digits+1);
    getchar;
}
```

So if I input 1111 it displays '4' that is correct, but when I type 0011 it displays '2', so how do I fix that?

Comment: Please show your code. The description is unclear and we need to see your code to be able to help point out what the problem may be with your attempt (we won't just write it for you).

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Every binary coded decimal digit is 4 bits. So the number of digits is the number of bits divided by 4. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @kaylum edited.

Comment: Parse it as a string not as an int. Just read it as a string and then call `strlen`. Should also add code to check it really does represent a binary number (only contains 1 and 0).

Comment: "0011"  is a string, it is not a number.

Comment: How can I parse 1 number as a string? I'm sorry I just started Computer Science course, but I don't get it.

Comment: If you don't know how to do a step you can search for it on Stackoverflow or other sites. Reading the manual pages for the library calls also helps. In this case read what `scanf_s` can do and how it can read a string. Though I would personally recommand using `fgets` instead.

Comment: Note that Binary Coded Decimal (BCD) is a special (and relatively uncommon) format where each group of 4 bits are used to store a decimal digit (e.g. 0000b to 1001b = 0 to 9), and some values aren't valid (1010b to 1111b). It's very unlikely that you're doing anything with BCD (and likely that you're confusing people by using the words "Binary Coded Decimal" in the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I type 0011 it displays '2', so how do I fix that?

Use `"%n"` to record the offset of the scan.

```
int n1;
int n2;
if (scanf_s(" %n%d%n", &bcd, &n1, &n2) == 1) {
  printf("Input %d\nNumber of digits is %d\n", bcd, n2 - n1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually using a binary-coded decimal, then this will work:

```
unsigned short count_bcd_digits(unsigned bcd)
{
    unsigned short count = 0;

    do {
        count++;
    } while(bcd >>= 4);

    return count;
}
```